# Bulk editing: can it be done without clogging the Top Questions page?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

It's become something of my hobby/quest to explore old MP&T posts. To seek out sets of related questions. <strike>To boldly go</strike> To find ways to improve the connections between them for future searchers. Often this involves edits -- of the title, the post, and/or the tags -- which bumps the post into the Top Questions list.

Case in point: I've compiled a list of ten (so far) questions on 4:3 polyrhythm. I'd like to go through and make adjustments to better connect them to each other. But for discussion's sake, let's allow for the possibility that all ten would receive edits of some kind. In that case, 10 of the 50 Top Questions would all be "modified by Aaron", which is annoying at best and can push more important items off the list.

**How can I pursue this "enterprise" without creating a nuisance?**

Comment: I thought you'd write "modified by It's HEDLEY", because you had that username recently. I didn't know that your username was Aaron back then.

Comment: @mathlander I changed by user name during the "hat bash", because it was a joke based on the hat I was using. But the name change caused enough confusion I may have to rethink the urge next time. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's only one way to change tags without bumping questions: when a ♦ moderator [merges a tag with another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/295232). There's a feature request [It should be possible to retag a question without bumping it to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29394/295232) but no response so far. Edits to title and body always bump the question. This may be annoying but otherwise there's no possibility for auditing by the community. There have been cases on Stack Overflow where even high-reputation users sort-of misused their edit privileges.

Whenever I do an operation like this (on other sites in the network, I hope it applies here as well) I try to *spread it out over a few days*. 10 questions is indeed on the high side, as the default size of the homepage is 15, not 50. Because most visitors are anonymous, they would see two thirds of the homepage being occupied by old questions.

Comment: I try to do my editing when others are also active, so there are never more than 3 'edited or answered' by me in a row but I can do more than 5 on a busy day. (Also not on this site.)

Comment: I hope you'll pardon the direct appeal, but I could use support for my MSE suggestion on [dealing with tagging/editing vs. bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358719/toward-resolving-longstanding-edits-cause-bumps-issues). Knowing you're a frequent "maintenance" editor, I hope you'll find merit in the approach. I've made a significant effort to incorporate both sides of the perennial discussion into a practical and straightforward proposal.

Comment: @Aaron I agree the community needs better tools for mass edits without bumping. I don't know what the best solution to the problem is, but your post is way above the average feature request, so +1.

Comment: Please accept my genuine thanks. If you're willing to leave a comment to that effect on Meta, I believe it would lend significant weight and validation to the post.