# New tag for repeats

Tags: support, tags

I've created a new tag (and suggested the tag wiki), I'm sure it will be useful: [repeats](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeats)

There are probably a few hundred old questions that ought to have this tag.  But, I'm not sure what the best way to get the old questions retagged without bumping them is.

I've already found thirty or so posts that should have this tag, and can list these below if that is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like the new tag, particularly the descriptions, which are clear, complete, and concise.

Unfortunately, retagging does bump the post. See for example, [Bulk editing: can it be done without clogging the Top Questions page?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3618/70803)

Answer (score 3):

### Update

Approximately 2 months later, and I've finally finished retagging roughly 120 posts to include the new [repeats](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeats) tag.  (I'm sure I missed some, but I am going to stop now.)

I would really like to apologise for continually restocking the active questions page with all of these old questions.  I tried to keep it to 2-3 retags per day, and did my best to edit in other improvements  to these posts at the same time.
However, I am sure other users have found this rather annoying, as it has pushed other (more worthy) questions out of the active page quicker than usual.
I can totally understand this objection, but apparently there really isn't any other way to get old posts retagged.

On Meta, I posted this question/complaint/rant which summarised this problem and documented a list of related questions:
[The system for adding a new tag to old questions is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379993/the-system-for-adding-a-new-tag-to-old-questions-is-broken)
but it hasn't received a proper response yet.

Overall, I've found the process to be very tedious, and I'm not really sure if it was worth it.

Comment: I have only praise for the efforts you made. The pacing in terms of number of retags on any particular day I thought was near perfect, and the overall effort of great value to the site. Not only is it valuable in helping keep the site organized and easy to search, but the churn of old questions allows for new or updated answers, or closing or re-opening or deleting posts in ways that might otherwise have gone long forgotten or ignored. Well done.